# Proper way to wait for all images to load before filling json file with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, image, onload

So i have the following problem: 
I have this getJson method where I use for loop with different operations to fill another json with data. In that loop I try to get the dimensions of all my image files (stored in the first json with their src) and to add them as another property in the second json. 
For that purpose I use the following code:

```
 $.getJSON("json.txt", function(myJsonData) {
         var elemID, elemType, elemURL, thumb, date, menuItem, imgH, imgW;

         for (key in myJsonData) {

             /*---Some operations for giving values all the variables---*/

             //Getting image dimensions
             var tempImg = new Image();
             tempImg.onload = function() {
                 imgW = this.width;
                 imgH = this.height;
                 console.log(imgW + 'x' + imgH);
                 loaded += 1;
             }
             tempImg.src = elemURL;

             //Filling the new json
             var newJsonData = {
                 "elemID": 'elemID_' + elemID,
                 "type": elemType,
                 "url": elemURL,
                 "thumbnail": thumb,
                 "menuItem": menuItem,
                 "date": date,
                 "W": imgW,
                 "H": imgH
             }
         }
     }
```

After that I have a function to generate html code for creating the dom of my page. 
The problem is - **the new json doesn't wait the onload function and I can't pass the dimensions of the images**. I was thinking of a way with using timeout or something but I am not sure it's a good practice. :/ Hope you guys can help.

Comment: Where is `data` defined ?

Comment: You're loading **the same image** inside `for..in` loop. Is it what you intended?

Comment: instead of data try to use myJsonData like for (key in myJsonData)

Comment: @hindmost - no, i have many images. I want to get the width and height for all of them and put it in the new Json. But things happen asynchronously i think, because when i console.log the image dimensions and the new json - the json is printed first. : /

Comment: @guest271314 - Sorry, that was my mistake. I fixed it now.

Comment: @Matzyschneider that was a mistake while pasting the code .. sorry about it : / It's not the problem.

Comment: I think `newJsonData` assignment should be inside `onload` callback

Comment: Have you thought about using a library, like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) or [es6-promises](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise)? Both have great methods for delaying function until all selected async operations are complete

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an array of jQuery deferred objects containing `newJsonData` , where `newJsonData` is defined and deferred object is resolved  within `img` `onload` handler ; return new promise object from `$.getJSON()` containing array of deferred objects.

Note, not certain where

```
var elemID, elemType, elemURL, thumb, date, menuItem, imgH, imgW;
```

are set to values other than `undefined` ?

```
$.getJSON("json.txt", function(myJsonData) {
         var elemID, elemType, elemURL, thumb, date, menuItem, imgH, imgW
         , arr = [];

         for (key in myJsonData) {

             /*---Some operations for giving values all the variables---*/

             //Getting image dimensions
             var tempImg = new Image();
             tempImg.onload = function() {
                 imgW = this.width;
                 imgH = this.height;
                 console.log(imgW + 'x' + imgH);
                 loaded += 1;
                 var dfd = new $.Deferred();
                 //Filling the new json
                 var newJsonData = {
                   "elemID": 'elemID_' + elemID,
                   "type": elemType,
                   "url": elemURL,
                   "thumbnail": thumb,
                   "menuItem": menuItem,
                   "date": date,
                   "W": imgW,
                   "H": imgH
                 };
                 arr.push(dfd.resolve(newJsonData))
             }
             tempImg.src = elemURL;

         };
         // $.when.apply($, arr).then(function() {
         //  do stuff with `newJsonData` objects
         //  console.log(arguments)
         // })
         return $.when.apply($, arr)
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo code which might help you - I'd highly recommend using a library to achieve this. I've used [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) in my example, specifically the `parallel` function.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("img");
var fns = Array.prototype.map.call(elems, function(current){

/*
  get image dimensions here, using the "current" argument
  make sure to return a function that takes a callback (async expects this)
  the callback itself takes two args, first is the error object,
  the second will be the dimension data
*/
    current.onload = function() {
        var dimensionData = { w: current.width, h: current.height };
        return function(callback){
            callback(null, dimensionData);
        }
    }
});

/*
  fns will now be an array of functions that take a single callback
  async will process all of these functions in parallel and, 
  once they're all complete, will call its own callback. in your case,
  results will be an array of dimensional data for each of your images and, 
  now that you know they've all loaded, can safely write it to the JSON
*/

async.parallel(fns, function(err, results){
    writeToJson(JSONData);
});
```

Will try to update this with a full example soon. Am a little busy at the moment.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution OP?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a jQuery [**`promise()`**](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) to do that :

```
$('<img/>', { src : elemURL }).promise().done(function(img) {
    //give some time to populate attributes to img
    setTimeout(function() {
       console.log(img[0].width, img[0].width);
    }, 200);     
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/udfs8e24/**

The timeOut is to give the browser some time to populate attributes to the dummy image. Without that, `img[0].width`, `img[0].width` **sometimes** will return 0,0 even though you can see that the `img` actually *do* have a width and height if it is consoled out. So instead your code could be something like :

```
$('<img/>', { src : elemURL }).promise().done(function(img) {
    setTimeout(function() {
       var newJsonData = {
          "elemID": 'elemID_' + elemID,
          "type": elemType,
          "url": elemURL,
          "thumbnail": thumb,
          "menuItem": menuItem,
          "date": date,
          "W": img[0].width,
          "H": img[0].height
       }
   }, 200)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100 percent sure of your issue but perhaps this might help.
Process the JSON text and then use a deferred to handle the result...probably needs some customization but should give you an example to base on.

```
// makeClass - By Hubert Kauker (MIT Licensed)
// original by John Resig (MIT Licensed).
function makeClass() {
    var isInternal;
    return function (args) {
        if (this instanceof arguments.callee) {
            if (typeof this.init == "function") {
                this.init.apply(this, isInternal ? args : arguments);
            }
        } else {
            isInternal = true;
            var instance = new arguments.callee(arguments);
            isInternal = false;
            return instance;
        }
    };
}
var ImagesClass = makeClass();
ImagesClass.prototype.init = function (elemID, elemType, elemURL, thumb, menuItem, adate, imgW, imgH) {
    this.elemID = 'elemID_' + elemID;
    this.type = elemType;
    this.url = elemURL;
    this.thumbnail = thumb;
    this.menuItem = menuItem;
    this.date = adate;
    this.W = imgW;
    this.H = imgH;
    this.newJsonData = {
        "elemID": this.elemID,
            "type": this.type,
            "url": this.url,
            "thumbnail": this.thumbnail,
            "menuItem": this.menuItem,
            "date": this.date,
            "W": this.W,
            "H": this.H
    };
};

var myimages = [];
var dfd = new $.Deferred();
dfd.done(function (imagearray) {
    //do something to process the array of images here - they are loaded in imagearray
});

var jqxhr = $.getJSON("json.txt");
jqxhr.done(function (myJsonData) {
    // HUGE assumption on my part that each myJsonData in json.txt contains each of these with these name:
    //  elemID, elemType, elemURL, thumb, date, menuItem, imgH, imgW
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(myJsonData);

    jQuery.map(obj, function (n, i) {
        var myImageObj = ImagesClass(n.elemID, n.elemType, n.elemURL, n.thumb, n.date, n.menuItem, n.imgH, n.imgW);
        myimages.push(myImageObj.newJsonData);
        dfd.resolve(myimages);
    });

});
jqxhr.fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
});
jqxhr.always(function () {
    console.log("complete");
});
```